# What is need of graph coloring?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

What is the practical application of graph coloring. In other words, why do we need to optimise number of colors(some important feature of a problem) using such algorithms.

Comment: sounds like ui.stackexchange.com to me

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. The coloring is just for visualizing the algorithm... what does the number of possible colors in "today's world" have anything to do with anything?

Comment: "Today's world have so many colors to color the graph"---yes, the situation has improved much since scientists invented color.

Comment: @jdog This has nothing to do with UI.

Comment: @diptesh Do I understand your question as: "Why do we need to restrict the amount of colours used in a graph to say 16, 20 , 100 when we have 16 million colours available?

Comment: There are an infinite number of colors. Computers just use a small subset of the total amount of visible wavelengths (usually integer wavelengths measured in nanometers) because obviously it is impossible to process the spectrum of colors to infinite precision. You would need infinite memory to distinguish the wavelength 270.0000000...(infinite 0s)...0 nm from 270.0000000...(infinite 0s)...1 nm.

Comment: yes jdog yes.
"Why do we need to restrict the amount of colours used in a graph to say 16, 20 , 100 when we have 16 million colours available?

Comment: see,I have updated question it may be easy to understand my question now.

Comment: @DipteshPatel, no, it still doesn't make any sense. You use this algorithm for applications where you have limits on the number of "colors" or you want to minimize them (as they represent some resource or similar restriction). If you've seen graph coloring used for a situation where you believe you have unlimited colors, please provide an example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that you have some misunderstanding of what is [graph coloring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring), possibly also of what is a [graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28mathematics%29).
Actual colors have nothing at all to do with this, graph coloring is used to solve problems where you have a limited amount of resources or other restrictions. The colors are just an abstraction for whatever resource you're trying to optimize, and the graph is an abstraction of your problem.

There are plenty of resources about graph theory on the web, so in a nutshell - a graph is an abstract representation of a set of elements (called vertices), some of which share a connection (called an edge). This of course is the most basic concept, there are many other attributes that can be added on top of that, such as directed edges, weights, and so on, but this concept should be enough for now.

Graphs are often used to model various real-world problems (and sometimes also made-up problems, because mathematicians and computer scientists still have to keep publishing papers after all), and we now have many algorithms that work on them efficiently (in terms of complexity), finding various attributed that may be interesting in order to solve the aforesaid problems. Alternatively, we can sometimes prove that a problem can not be solved with any efficient algorithm. Graph coloring is one of these (or more accurately, the questions: `can a graph be colored in up to k colors`, or the question `what is the minimal number of colors needed to color the graph`), unless we're dealing with certain subtypes of graphs, such as planar graphs (an map of neighboring countries is a good example as it was used for some interesting graph coloring proofs). Coloring here means attaching a "color" or a number to each vertice such that no two vertices with a connecting edge have the save value.

**An example of a real life problem** where graph coloring may be applied: you design a compiler, at a given program you observe N variables, and would like to allocate as many of them into registers as possible (the rest would have to be spilled out to memory, which is slower and best avoided). However, your CPU has only, say, 16 logical registers in total. However, on the bright side - you know which variables are used in the same context and time, and which aren't. Obviously, ones that aren't alive together can use the same register. So, can you allocate all the variables into the existing register set?

To solve this, you can build a graph with variables being the vertices, and where an edge connects each two variables that are used at the same timeframe. Coloring that graph in the minimal number of "colors" would tell you how many registers you need in total, as each color can be assigned to a register, and thanks to the coloring premise - no 2 variables alive simultaneously can use the same "color" (register), since they would be connected by an edge and can not be colored the same way.

Comment: Very thorough answer! Do you have any resource where the use of graph coloring on compilers is further developed?

Comment: @PeterPetigru , there's a chapter in any decent textbook on compilers (including the famous dragon book), but if you want something online you can start with the wiki page - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_allocation

Answer (score 3):

A [Sudoku solver](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/07/29/graph-colouring-part-five.aspx) is a classic example of where graph colouring comes in handy.

Note that the number of colours here is restricted by the rules of the game. 'Colours' in graph colouring algorithms are often figurative rather than literal. Sudoku is more often played with the numbers 1-9 than colours, but that doesn't stop graph colouring being relevant.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of practical applications that depend on graph coloring. For example, *Frequency assignment to cellular antennas* is a famous problem. In this problem, one can only use small number of frequencies(colors), and assign them to the antennas such that clients always connect to one of the antennas. Problem arises when coverage area of several antennas overlap, and in this case we want to have at least one antenna with unique frequency(color). One cannot use simple *proper(non-monotonic)* coloring in this problem.

In above case, we deal with *colouring of hypergraph*. We define hypergraph according to the coloring problem. And there are different variants of colorings, like *Conflict-free coloring*, *Unique-maximum coloring*. Many research have been done in case of static situations, where hypergraph do not change over time. And there are many interesting research going on in case of *online Setting*, where hyper edge may change in time (say some antenna stops working, or new antenna is fixed at some location).

you can also refer **[1](http://arxiv.org/abs/1005.3616)** survey paper to read more about interesting coloring problems and its applications.